# installing php-mysql on centos 6

Tags: nginx, centos6, php5

I've installed MariaDB for my database and Nginx on my computer that running Centos 6 . when i want to install php-mysql driver i get this problem :

**# yum install php-mysql**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.gtcomm.net
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.iweb.com
 * extras: mirror.agmn.ca
 * updates: centos.mirror.gtcomm.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
Package mysql-libs is obsoleted by MariaDB-shared, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
Package mysql-libs is obsoleted by MariaDB-shared, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
Package mysql-libs is obsoleted by MariaDB-shared, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
Package mysql-libs is obsoleted by MariaDB-shared, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i also tried `--skip-broken` and `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` but ro result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have installed MariaDB from the packages provided by the project. You first need to install the equivalent MariaDB-compat RPM from MariaDB before you can install these packages. This package provides compatibility with distribution packages which are expecting the older version of MySQL which CentOS comes with.

Comment: but MariaDB works flawlessly in my system , i got that errors when i wanna install php-mysql driver !!

Comment: You forgot to install the -compat package, as I already said.

Comment: But it's installed already and i can't install it anyway . it says `Package MariaDB-compat-5.5.36-1.el6.i686 already installed and latest version Nothing to do`

Comment: @OnlyMAJ Yes, you installed the wrong package. That's the 32-bit package, and you are on a 64-bit system. Again, install the correct package.